# Fixing timestamp description in review suspension window when the suspension period is over

Tags: bug, timestamps

I had recently been suspended from reviewing, but the suspension period was over yesterday. I had the suspension window open from previous days and noticed a funny message about when I will be able to review again.

> You’ve been suspended from reviewing. You will be able to review again 22 hours ago.

I have no idea how to fix this error, but I thought I'd share it with you in case someone might find a way to make it look better in the future.

Here's a screenshot of the message:

[image: screenshot of the suspension message]

Comment: Well... that's weird.

Comment: Not sure this is something worth fixing. I'd expect extremely few people to leave the tab open on that specific message. Therefore, there are extremely few people who would be affected. And the impact is extremely low, as well.

Comment: It's the kind of "bug" my boss would excitedly call me about when I'm trying to work on fixing an issue with payment systems, for example.

Comment: @yivi I wasn't sure which tag I should've used.

Comment: I guess that technically it is a bug. Although I doubt its relative importance.

Comment: Frankly, this is still a bug - meaning the counter does not take into account negative values. This is clearly a failure state, so the message should change to present the user with options as to what to do next - from the frontend standpoint, there is no difference between a user who left the tab for too long, incorrect suspension duration received from the backend, or a system failure resulting the suspension to continue despite the timer running out.

Comment: SO has simply invented a time machine. Nothing worrying about.